# <iframe> background change on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to change the `<iframe>` background when my form is submitted, but I'm having a really hard time getting it to work.

This is my sample HTML code. I can't fiddle it, because then the `<iframe>` would come from another URL, and because of iframe's cross-origin restrictions won't work at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myframe").contentDocument.body.style.background = "red";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form onsubmit="myFunction()" id="myframe" action="demo_form.asp" method="post" target="frame">
  <label>First name:<input type="text" name="fname"></label>
  <label>Last name:<input type="text" name="lname"></label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<iframe name="frame">

</body>
</html>
```

To demo live, you can go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_target) and replace it with my code.

Please help me, this should be easy. I'm not very skilled in JavaScript as you may have understood by now. I'm trying to use pure JS and not jQuery on this code. The worst part is that the JS code works when not related to a form, but with a simple button onclick event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myframe").contentDocument.body.style.background = "red";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">hei</button>
<iframe id="myframe" src="demo_iframe.htm"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

(copy to the same link as above to demo live)

By the way, please don't link to w3fools.com as I'm normally not on W3Schools, however it was the only site I could find where I could modify my code and example `<iframe>`s were stored on the same URL.

Comment: You cannot access iframe inner content from parent page if both on 2 different domains.

Comment: The `<iframe>` source and the form URL are on the same domain, as stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others wondering about my question without getting any help from what's already stated, I will post my final code for others to see. What I had to do was to have an `<iframe>` load event listener inside the `<form>` submit event listener. This will guarantee that the form is submitted before changing the CSS, unlike `onclick` solutions on `<input type="submit">` (one can submit `<form>`s without using a mouse).

```
<form onsubmit="iframebackground()" target="frame"></form>
<iframe name="frame" id="myframe">
<script>
function iframebackground() {
    document.getElementById("myframe").addEventListener("load", function(){
        this.contentDocument.body.style.background = red;
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`myframe` is the ID of your **form**, not your iframe.

You are also trying to change the background of the document in the frame immediately before you load a new document into it which would discard the one with the changed background.

Approach this by having the server deliver a document with the right background colour in response to the form submission instead.

Comment: @AmrElGarhy — Because, before I spotted the other problems, this looked like a "You made a typo" question. This wouldn't have been a "real" answer. Putting a community wiki one down discourages people from copying comments into answers.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo unlike my real code, but it still doesn't work. Now it flashes red, though.